# React setState not affecting Children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, state

I use **[CKEditor](https://github.com/codeslayer1/react-ckeditor)** For a simple mail form in react, which looks like this:

```
class SimpleForm extends Component{
constructor() {
    super();
    this.updateContent = this.updateContent.bind(this);
    this.state = {
    title: "MyTitle",
    CKEditorContent: 'text here',
    newMail: false,
    }
    this.baseState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {newMail: true});
}
}

updateContent(newContent) {
      console.log(newContent);
      this.setState({
          CKEditorContent: newContent.editor.getData(),
      })}

clearText(){
      this.setState(this.baseState);
    }

render() {
    return (
          <div>
              <CKEditor
                activeClass="p10"
                content={this.state.CKEditorContent}
                events={{
                  "change": this.updateContent
                }}
              />
                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  label="clear"
                  secondary={true}
                  onClick={this.clearText.bind(this)}
                />
          </div>
    );
}
}
```

The problem is, that although setState is called correctly - both this.title and this.CKEditorContent have their values reset, BUT the internals of CKeditor field remain unchanged.

before click:
[image]
after click CLEAR:
[image]

Comment: Just real quickly, your missing a comma after your first key value pair in this.state

Comment: thanks, fixed, but no result changed. It was just mistake while editing code for stack.

Comment: Just process of elimination, have you tried manually setting the state after clear without using your base state? 
Also I didn't see any function bindings, are you missing those?
If a manual set works, its probably object.keys

Comment: Yes I tried that approach. function binding is in Constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/codeslayer1/react-ckeditor/issues/13) you need to use CKEditor's `setData` method to manipulate the state of the input.

So in your case the workaround would be to modify the code like so:

```
    <CKEditor
      activeClass="p10"
      content={this.state.CKEditorContent}
      events={{
        change: this.updateContent,
      }}
      ref={(instance) => { this.ckeditor = instance; }}
    />
```

And then in your `clearText()` function just call it like this:

`this.ckeditor.editorInstance.setData('');`